# How to use ng-repeat with an array of objects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to populate a table using ng-repeat with data from an array of objects, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Here's what my array of objects looks like (from the console.log):

```js
schedule1: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] 0: Object
elevenAm: "open"
fivePm: "open"
fourPm: "open"
nineAm: "open"
noon: "open"
onePm: "open"
scheduleDate: "Thu Oct 27th"
techName: "Ashley Cox"
tenAm: "open"
threePM: "open"
twoPm: "open"
__proto__: Object1: ObjectelevenAm: "open"
fivePm: "open"
fourPm: "open"
nineAm: "open"
noon: "open"
onePm: "open"
scheduleDate: "Thu Oct 27th"
techName: "Nancy Hall"
tenAm: "open"
threePM: "open"
twoPm: "open"
__proto__: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Objectlength: 6__proto__: Array[0]

Here's a snipet of my HTML:

<md-tabs>
        <md-tab class="all-tabs" label="Today">
            
            <table border="1" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>schedule1 date</th>
                        <th>Technician</th>
                        <th>9 AM</th>
                        <th>10 AM</th>
                        <th>11 AM</th>
                        <th>Noon</th>
                        <th>1 PM</th>
                        <th>2 PM</th>
                        <th>3 PM</th>
                        <th>4 PM</th>
                        <th>5 PM</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in controller.schedule1">
                        <td>{{item.scheduleDate}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.techName}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.nineAm}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.nineAm}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.tenAm}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.elevenAm}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.noon}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.onePm}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.twoPm}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.threePm}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.fourPm}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.fivePm}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </md-tab>

    </md-tabs>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?   I have other pages from this site that work with ng-repeat perfectly.

Comment: I believe schedule1 is *itself* an **array of size 1**.  Can you test if it prints anything for controller.schedule1[0].  As with Javascript,, typeof Array is Object.

Comment: Sure!  Here's the result:    schedule1[0] is: [object Object]

Comment: I also added these console.logs to confirm that the data exists:    schedule1.scheduleDate[0] is: Thu Oct 27th                schedule1.techName[0] is: Ashley Cox                                        schedule1.tenAm[0] is: open

Comment: I just can't help it, but notice that every element has `__proto__` set to next element in order, like a linked list or a graph.  Is this a serialized data from a backend.  But in any case, way over my head!!